# get first value in Pymodm

Tags: python, pymongo, pymodm

I would like to check if the username given during the registration of a user already exists using pymodm with a clear solution similar to this one using pymongo:

```
if users.find_one({"username": username}) is not None:
     print("This username already exists")
```

To make this code I would have to write :

```
try :
    user = User.objects.get({'username': username})
except errors.DoesNotExist:
    user = None
if user is not None:
    print("This username already exists")
```

Because pymodm uses expections. It is very inefficient and heavy to code. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `count()` will count the number of entry in the returned `get()` request. However the get request already raises an exception when no data is available.

Comment: `count()` is not using the index that the username (*should be an indexed attribute in order to use the index db joy*) so you need to assess how many users are in total (not optimal) instead of just finding one using an indexed field. This can make your login action a paradise for coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, threading is not the most optimal way, but, in this case, it's slightly the same effect than to keep open a listener waiting for a callback when the db request is ready.

Your code is redundant, as the exception already checks your `if` statement. Do it like:

```
try :
     user = User.objects.get({'username': username})
     print("This username already exists")
except errors.DoesNotExist:
     # You can create the user     
     print("This username can be used")
```

And also think about creating an [index](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.IndexModel) in the username field, or, perform the user find operation using an indexed field *you may already have*, which will make your application nicer in terms of performance.